# How to get all existing post types

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm working on carousel slider plugin. So far so good! But i want the user to be able to select which post type the slider must slide.

Wordpress does have a function called: `get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator);`

But this function has an argument called '_builtin' (bool). True returns all standard wordpress post_types like 'post, 'page' and 'attachement'. False returns all custom post types.

What I want is to return both.

```
    public function post_type() {
        $args = array( 
            'public'    => true,
            '_builtin'  => true or false // I want this to return both true and false
        );

        $get_post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names', $output);

        return $get_post_types;
        //var_dump($get_post_types);
    }
```

**Actual Question**

Is there some kind of workaround so i can select both true and false or is it recommended to write my own custom wpdb query? Or is there some kind of method to select true and false?

*p.s. i use this function in a class so that explains the "public" keyword*

Comment: have you tried with empty args : `get_post_types([], "names")` ?

Comment: @mmm , Tried it and it worked! Thanks a lot it cost me 2 hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mmm

The solution in this case is pretty simple.
Just pass an empty `$args` array. Then it neglects the default '_builtin'

**Example**

```
$get_post_types = get_post_types( $args = array(), $output, $operator );
return $get_post_types;
```